# Suggestions do not pop up if I'm not in a function scope

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

This images below are from a header `.h` file. As seen, If I am in the scope of a function, typing `RCC->` pops up the options, however, if I am not in the scope of any function, then it does not show them. What's the reason for that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the hints only show up in a scope where it thinks they make sense. The global scope could end up cluttered with all kinds of nonsense, so it might not suggest anything there to avoid looking dumb.

Comment: @tadman but let's say I will make something like `#define xxxxx() (RCC->AHB1ENR = 0x00`). Why this is nonsense?

Comment: I mean if there's too many matches the suggestions will be nonsense as everything will match. If you want to make macros like that and you want auto-complete, compose them in the function body, then move them to the right location after.

Comment: #define is not C only preprocesor. Intellisense knows it. Preprocessor does not know anything about C.

Comment: @P__J__ ok, so, I won't get  / shouldn't expect suggestions for macro definitions?

Comment: No you will not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only place the code in the function body. You try to do it outside the function. That is the reason. Intellisense knows it and does not suggest it.

Same is with macros. Preprocessor does not know anything about the C language. In the macro definition it acts exactly the same way.

I personally do not like this kind of macros. Use normal inline functions for that. If you enable optimisations (even -Og) the function will be inlined

https://godbolt.org/z/yd75jH

Comment: did you mean "I personally do **not** like ......." ? by the way, I have never heard about inline functions, I'll have a look at them.

Comment: hi, do you have any idea for the cause of the following case in the video?https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nASopSS4xuJQZvnKU9gep77eZLB9B1Rr/view?usp=sharing